# Eclipse link jpa cache issue

Tags: database, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, hana

I am using eclipse link jpa 2.0. I am using hana database. So I created views and generated java entity files using eclipse. The problem is, after starting Java Web application in Tomcat server 7, if any table data is modified, then view is not returning updated values. Even if I am running view with native query it is giving old values only.. please let me know what changes need to do in configuration level or entity creating level. ( I even added @Cacheable(false) also).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that when you say *view* you mean *database views*, perhaps the following existing answered question might help (though the link talks about Oracle instead):

[Materialized View - Oracle / Data is not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37399298/materialized-view-oracle-data-is-not-updating)

You might be using some sort of *materialized view* made in the database that can be configured to refresh during certain events. In this case, the problem does not lie in Eclipselink's caching mechanisms, but in your database instead (as you mentioned that even native queries returned stale data).